# URL links when clicked causing app to crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I've never had this problem before version `1.0.51`, but every time I click on a url link, for example clicking on someones JSFiddle from within the android app it crashes. I'm running android version `4.4.2` (KitKat).

Comment: Mind posting a link to a post where you are able to reproduce this from?

Comment: [Link to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754014/jquery-animate-to-left-or-right-from-variable). When I click on the OP's JSFiddle, the app will crash. Note this happens with all urls contained within questions, answers and comments.

Comment: Awesome, will be fixed in next build, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in version 1.0.53 releasing out to beta users as we speak.

Comment: Yay great news, will have to wait for the final release.